# How do I get Xpath of this table correct?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%">
   <tbody><tr>
      <td width="18%" valign="top"><b>**Member Id:<**/b></td>
      <td width="36%" valign="top"><b>**00600**</b></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td valign="top"><b>**Unit Name**:</b></td>
      <td colspan="3" valign="top"><b>**A. D. ENGINEERING WORKS**</b></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td width="18%" valign="top"><b>**Contact Person**:</b></td>
      <td valign="top">
        <p align="left">**S.p. Sharma**</p></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the Html code
I am extracting member id, unit name and contact person. Can anyone provide me with the correct xpath for this
**Update - Here is my spider code**

```
 def parse(self, response):

 hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

 titles = hxs.select('//table//tr')

 items = []

 for titles in titles:

       item = AmazonItem()

       item ["Member"] = titles.select("table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/b").extract()
       item ["unit name"] = titles.select("table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/b").extract()
       item ["contact person"] = titles.select("table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/b").extract()
       items.append(item)
  return items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, provided that this is the entire HTML you are reading:

MemberId:

```
"table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/b"
```

Unit name:

```
"table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/b"
```

Contact person:

```
"table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/b"
```

**EDIT**:  Fixed the XPath queries according to the coment by hielsnoppe below.  Was selecting the first td (the field name), but not td number 2, the actual value.

Comment: This selects the field names, but not the actual values. To select the actual values use `td[2]` instead of `td[1]`.

Comment: @HaukurHaf see my update I am not getting titles = hxs.select('//table//tr')

Comment: You have a tbody tag in there as well.  Try this xpath query: "//table/tbody/tr" to get all tr tags.

Comment: @HaukurHaf you mean titles = hxs.select('//table/tbody/tr')

Comment: yes, I guess so.  I only specified the actual XPath query - I'm not familiar with the library you are using to execute it :-)

Comment: @HaukurHaf yeah i got that. I am using scrapy.